# Как правильно преобразовать ЧЧ:ММ:СС в секунды?

Tags: php, время

Как правильно преобразовать ЧЧ:ММ:СС в секунды на php?

Comment: В секунды какие? Начиная с начала текущих суток? В unixtime?

Comment: У меня цифры постоянные. Это как, например, продолжительность музыки или фильма. Просто нужно перевести ЧЧ:ММ:СС в секунды и все.

Comment: Вам длительность ЧЧ:ММ:СС в длительность в секундах перевести надо?

Comment: Да,  splash58 написал уже как сделать. Спасибо что откликнулись.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться функцией  strtotime, только нужно вычесть полночь, поскольку она делает время сегодняшнего дня

```
echo strtotime("12:10:45") - strtotime("00:00:00") ."\n" . (12*60*60+10*60+45);
```

получается

```
43845
43845
```

Answer (score 3):

Вот более простой способ:

```
$time = '23:14:16';
echo strtotime("1970-01-01 $time UTC");
```